# Unable to use Typography - TypeError: Cannot read property '@global' of undefined

Tags: material-ui, react-admin

I'm trying react-admin 2.4.4 and that whenever I include a Typography component the following error is displayed:

> TypeError: Cannot read property '@global' of undefined...  in WithStyles(Typography)

It seems the problem is related to unexpected structure on theme styles but can't understand why. 
I saw some references pointing that it could be due to different material-ui/core dependencies mixed in the same project.

Any ideas about how to troubleshoot this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this by making sure there's no mixed versions of material-ui dependencies in the project.

Comment: Just note that if you use `react-admin`, it depends on material-ui/core `1.x` (check package `ra-ui-materialui` in your node_modules to make sure)

Comment: @KimKha, thanks for your valuable comment. It helped me.

Comment: This is whats biting me now, I'm trying to setup my yarn resolutions to set material version to 1.x for react-admin, failing at it.